# Find Confirmation Code (FindBug.io)

Tags: password-cracking, burp-suite, web-crypto-api

I have solve half of the problem by decoding a base64 code that reveal the next URL(https://app.findbug.io/app/task/FinDBuG-CTF2019) but now i don't know what to find or where i tried it with burpsuite.
H[image]ere is the link for confirmation code:https://app.findbug.io/app/hacker/task

[image]

Comment: `curl -X OPTIONS target`

Comment: Or to fit this situation, change GET to OPT `OPTIONS /app/task/FinDBuG-CTF2019 HTTP/1.1` and repeat the request:

Comment: but what im gonna find there i dont see any confirmation code just an alowed post and all json token.

Comment: And it was the same thing again just with the POST method. Thank You!

Comment: Usually questions for personal purpose are not intended to be asked on a HQ forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is use HTTP OPTIONS [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) and look at the response then work your way from there